# Subsetting multiple columns of a data.table with the same column name

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have the following data.table:

```
dt <- data.table(a = 1:3, b = 4:6, a = 7:9)

# dt
   a b a
1: 1 4 7
2: 2 5 8
3: 3 6 9
```

How do I subset the data.table so that all columns with the name `a` get selected?

The code below gives me only the first match.

```
dt[, "a", with = F]

   a
1: 1
2: 2
3: 3
```

Comment: It's a very bad practice to have identical column names. Consider renaming it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a logical vector to select columns.

```
library(data.table)
dt[, names(dt) == 'a', with = FALSE]

#   a a
#1: 1 7
#2: 2 8
#3: 3 9
```

Answer (score 5):

I recommend using `.SDcols`:

```
dt[ , .SD, .SDcols = patterns('^a$')]
```

Answer (score 1):

`dt[,grep("a",names(dt)),with=FALSE]`